# Insert data from an input inside a table row

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 4 to create a frontend app for a project. I have a table formed by 3 rows that I have to populate with data from another input.

[image]

As I click the button "aggiungi prodotto" the first row of the table should be populated, then the second one and last the third row.

How can I obtain this?

Tell me if you need more information.

Comment: how does your table code look like?

Comment: Assuming you are using angular material table, can you look at the `renderRows()` method from the `Methods` section here: https://material.angular.io/components/table/api ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/OGHu53q   ( I know its a mess )

this is my <td> , im using Mdl light.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an array with 3 items with no values, and set the table rows using `*ngFor`. and on every click on the button set the next item in the array to the form values.
The variables -

```
myArray: any[] = [{ propA: '', propB: ''... }, { propA: '', propB: ''... }, { propA: '', propB: ''... } ];
count = 0;
```

In the table -
`<tr *ngFor="let row in myArray">tds...</tr>`

And on click -

```
myArray[this.count] = newFormData;
this.count++;
```